# Java Spark collect() javaRdd fails with Memory errors (EMR cluster)

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, emr, amazon-emr

Im running Spark App on AWS EMR(Elastic Map Reduce) cluster
**My master node characteristics are:** 8 vCore, 15 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage
My executors node are: 8 vCore, 15 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage

I have csv **inputFile**  file with size - 600MB.I am trying to read it to JavaRdd and then use collect() to convert it to List of objects.

Here is my code:

```
JavaRDD<WebLabPurchasesDataObject> allRecords = context.textFile(inputFile).map (
        data -> {
            String[] fields = data.split(",", -1);

            String hitDay = fields[0];
            String treatmentName = fields[1];
            String sessionId = fields[2];

            return new WebLabPurchasesDataObject(hitDay,treatmentName,sessionId);   
        });

allRecords.cache();

List<WebLabPurchasesDataObject> webLabRddAllRecordsList = allRecords.collect();
```

Everytime I try to run this code, I get  **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**. 
As far as I understand Spark is performing **collect()** operation on my master node. So is there any way to increase the memory, so it would be able to run the program?

```
18/03/15 16:35:48 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, ip-1443-405-18-1544.us-west-2.compute.internal): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    18/03/15 16:35:49 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on ip-43ew55-154.us-west-2.compute.internal: remote Akka client disassociated
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with us. By the way: Do you have any question?

Comment: Questions is that I OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, everytime I run this code. How can I increase memory ?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose this is not a duplicate. I added more info. I run Spark app on aws EMR cluster

Comment: I have reopened the question. Next time, be precise, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have identified, since the results are collected on the driver, you need to increase the driver memory. the default value is 1GB which is turning out to be insufficient for your case.

Add this config when you are creating SparkSession/SparkContext: `spark.driver.memory` with a greater value: `2g` or `3g`. 
If you are using spark-shell then pass this as additional option while starting spark-shell: `--driver-memory 3g` for 3GB memory.

I also suggest you to read more about configurations described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help! When I try to set "spark.driver.memory" ="5g", I'm getting different error: : Exception while getting task result
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Comment: Sorry, I missed to include another conf along with driver memory: `spark.driver.maxResultSize` You should set it to how much large objects you are going to collect. I suggest you set it `0` (unlimited) which implies you could use as much memory available with the driver to collect results.

Comment: Let me know if this works, I'll update the answer in that case.

Comment: Thanks! Will try with maxResultSize. Do I need to cache() my javaRdd before perform collect() ? If yes, waht StorageLevel I need to set to my persist() function?

Comment: Cache/persist won't affect this OOM error as this is due to driver memory. But Caching would sure improve performance, given you have sufficient memory available on executors.